# Is there a way via excel vba to check the contents of a msgbox displayed by an external macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose that I am creating a macro that needs to call another excel application's macro which I DO NOT HAVE ACCESS OR RIGHTS TO CHANGE ITS CODE.

Now, in my macro that is calling that other excel application, whenever that other excel application displays a MSGBOX, the process in my macro stops unless I click that MSGBOX.

Now I want to be able to get the message in the displayed MSGBOX and also be able to click its "OK" button.

Is that possible via vba (which means no user interaction)?

BTW, I am using Application.Run to run the other excel application's macro which will create another instance.(Since it spawns 2 MS Excel processes in the Task Manager)

Comment: Not an expert on this but likely you will need to use Windows API for that.  Eg see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=366892&seqNum=3

Comment: When you say "external macro" what do you mean? Is there an "external application" running on your computer, but not in Excel? What I want to emphasize is that it is possible, but not in case of a MsgBox shown by the same session VBA. When such a message appears, VBA is paused. You need another application to wait, intercept and press the button...\

Comment: You would want to find out why the message box is appearing and do a check for that condition, which means you would need to have access to the source code.

Comment: What did you update? Can you clearly specify what is the "external application" showing that MsgBox? Is it an addin? Another password protected slxm workbook?

Comment: It is another Excel Application that I am calling in my own excel application via vba

Comment: That is still pretty unhelpful. Is it a macro that you call from your macro?

Comment: I have updated it once again.  Sorry english is bad.

Comment: @GSerg Yes it is.

Comment: You keep complicating things unnecessarily. E.g. "Excel application" may refer to another instance of Excel (which may make a difference) or to another macro-enabled Excel file in the same instance of Excel. You seem to be using these terms interchangeably.

Comment: Assuming that you meant that you, from your macro, call another macro that is in another workbook, and that other macro displays a message box, then no, you cannot do anything about it, because it's not your code that is currently executing. You could only do something from a yet another instance of Excel, but even then you couldn't pass the contents of the message box to your original still-running macro or even make it so that it could regain control and read it, because your code in the first Excel would be completely blocked until that other macro finishes.

Comment: Q seems clear to me @jaypax123, but for the benefit of those who seem to be unsure, you could add the code you are using to call the other macro to your Q

Comment: @GSerg I am sorry if I was unclear with regards to it being the same instance or a different one. But, based on your comment, what I want to do is impossible whether it is the same instance or a different instance.

Comment: @jaypax123 re your last edit,  please post the _actual  code_ you use to run that other macro.  I'm beginning to think you don't understand what _another instance_ actually means,  or how that may help solve your problem.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, would it help if it was a different instance? I understand what a different instance is. I dont want to post my codes since it is in another machine with no access to the internet. BUT if you say that it will help if it is a different instance, then I will POST it.

Comment: It might (can't test ATM).  Speculating, that might allow you to continue executing code in the first instance, while the other macro runs.  Then use a Windows API to hook the MsgBox

Comment: @chrisneilsen ok. I will try first Windows API. Then post here my findings.

Comment: It seems like it would be much easier to first know the reason why the message box is appearing, and then in your code, make sure that condition does not exist before you run the code that you cannot modify.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Regardless of whether it's the same instance Excel or not, how can you call another macro and continue execution without waiting for it to finish?

Comment: @jaypax123 I've run a little test.  Running the other macro from Excel itself, even in a seperate instance, still block the VBA.  But, you can achieve a non-blocking method by launching Excel, Opening the other file, and executing its macro from a VBScript.  So. in your main Excel file, you'd use `Shell "wscript c:\Path\To\Script.vbs", vbNormalFocus` to run the VBScript.  ...

Comment: Continued... That script  would create a Excel instance, Open the file, and run the macro.  Once the `Shell` command has exectuted, that VBA continues to run.  Your main code would need to wait (or use an event, or somethin else) for the MsgBox to apear, and use a API to hook it.

Comment: @GSerg you are right, but I thought of another way.  See above comment to OP

Comment: @jaypax123: Is the other workbook VBProject password protected? Can you write here a sample of what the message box show? Maybe it is good to move our focus in correcting of the things found by that application...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I want by using SendKeys. 
Basically what I did was:

```
SendKeys "^c" 'copies the text inside the MsgBox
SendKeys "~" 'clicks the "OK" button
Application.Run (OtherExcel.xlsm!Module1.Function)
```

I don't know why but it works. All I need to do now is to get the copied text from the clipboard.